# Paypal developer/business account(sandbox)

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm working on a php project that needs to integrate Paypal API's. I've chosen REST API's. But I've a business account(sandbox). Is it possible to call REST API's using this account type?

Comment: You should directly talk to paypal customer services for any details:
https://developer.paypal.com/support/

Answer (score 0):

You need to log into developer.paypal.com using any live PayPal account, via https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications

If you don't have a live PayPal account, create one.

Once logged in, the number of REST API apps and corresponding sandbox accounts that you can manage is unlimited.